# Cannot use Figure in Standalone

Tags: floats, captions

I am trying to create a standalone pdf with the following source code:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw[fill=teal] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Rectangle in TikZ}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This does not work, outputting the following:

```
    Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \\item.
    Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \\item.
    Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \\item.
    Missing \\endgroup inserted.\n<inserted text> 
    Missing \\endgroup inserted.\n<inserted text> 
    Missing \\endgroup inserted.\n<inserted text> 
    Missing } inserted.\n<inserted text> 
    Undefined control sequence.\n<argument> \\csname fnum@\\@captype 
    Extra \\endgroup.\n\\@caption ...me }{\\ignorespaces #3}\\par \\endgroup 
    Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \\item.
    \\begin{document} ended by \\end{figure}.
    Extra \\endgroup.\n<recently read> \\endgroup 
    Extra \\endgroup.\n\\color@endgroup ->\\endgraf \\endgroup 
    Too many }'s.\n\\endsa@boxit ...dvarwidth \\color@endgroup \\egroup
```

Does anybody here know how to work around this problem? Using a documentclass other than standalone is an option for me, as long as it renders a pdf that matches the size of the content.